# Does Lucene Support Unicode?

Tags: c#, asp.net, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

I am building a full text search facility for my website coded in asp.net mvc with mysql database. This website is for a non-english language. I have started work on it using Lucense as the engine for searching the text, but I can't find any info on whether it supports unicode?

Does anyone have any information on whether Lucene supports Unicode? I don't want a nasty surprise..

Also links to beginner articles on implementing lucene.net will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm highly recommend Lucene in Action http://www.amazon.com/Lucene-Action-Otis-Gospodnetic/dp/1932394281

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. It fully support unicode.
But for analyzing you should explicitly  assign appropriate stemmers and correct stopwords.
As for sample. Here is copy from our last project

```
directory = new RAMDirectory();
            analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(version, new Hashtable());
            var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, analyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenStatelessSession())
            {
                organizations = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Organization)).List<Organization>();
                foreach (var organization in organizations)
                {
                    var document = new Document();
                    document.Add(new Field("Id", organization.ID.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
                    document.Add(new Field("FullName", organization.FullName, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
                    document.Add(new Field("ObjectTypeInvariantName", typeof(Organization).FullName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
                    indexWriter.AddDocument(document);
                }

                var persistentType = typeof(Order);
                var classMetadata = DbContext.SessionFactory.GetClassMetadata(persistentType);


                var properties = new List<PropertyInfo>();
                for (int i = 0; i < classMetadata.PropertyTypes.Length; i++)
                {
                    var propertyType = classMetadata.PropertyTypes[i];
                    if (propertyType.IsCollectionType || propertyType.IsEntityType) continue;
                    properties.Add(typeof(Order).GetProperty(classMetadata.PropertyNames[i]));
                }

                orders = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Order)).List<Order>();
                var idProperty = typeof(Order).GetProperty(classMetadata.IdentifierPropertyName);

                foreach (var order in orders)
                {
                    var document = new Document();
                    document.Add(new Field("Id", idProperty.GetValue(order, null).ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
                    document.Add(new Field("ObjectTypeInvariantName", typeof(Order).FullName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
                    foreach (var property in properties)
                    {
                        var value = property.GetValue(order, null);
                        if (value != null)
                        {

                            document.Add(new Field(property.Name, value.ToString(), Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED_NO_NORMS));
                        }
                    }
                    indexWriter.AddDocument(document);
                }
                indexWriter.Optimize(true);
                indexWriter.Commit();
                return indexWriter.GetReader();
            }
```

I'm querying Organization objects from NHibernate and put them into Lucene.NET

Here is simple search

```
var searchValue = textEdit1.Text;

                var parser = new QueryParser(version, "FullName", analyzer);
                parser.SetLocale(new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
                Query query = parser.Parse(searchValue);
                var indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(directory, true);

                var docs = indexSearcher.Search(query, 10);
                lblSearchTotal.Text = string.Format(totalPattern, docs.totalHits, organizations.Count() + orders.Count);
                resultPanel.Controls.Clear();
                foreach (var found in docs.scoreDocs)
                {
                    var document = indexSearcher.Doc(found.doc);
                    var objectId = document.Get("Id");
                    var objectType = document.Get("ObjectTypeInvariantName");

                    if (resultPanel.Controls.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var labelSeparator = CreateSeparatorLabelControl();
                        resultPanel.Controls.Add(labelSeparator);
                    }
                    var labelCard = CreateFoundLabelControl();
                    resultPanel.Controls.Add(labelCard);

                    var organization = organizations.Where(o => o.ID.ToString() == objectId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (organization != null)
                    {
                        labelCard.Text = string.Format("<b>{0}</b></br>{1}", organization.AccountNumber, organization.FullName);
                        labelCard.Tag = organization;
                        //labels[count].Text = string.Format("<b>{0}</b></br>{1}", organization.AccountNumber, organization.FullName);
                        //labels[count].Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        labelCard.Text = string.Format("Найден объект типа '{0}' с идентификатором '{1}'", objectType, objectId);
                        labelCard.Tag = mainForm.GetObject(objectType, objectId); 
                    }
                    labelCard.Visible = true;
                    //count++;
                }
```

Comment: also NHibernate Search can be used.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, Lucene supports unicode because it stores strings in UTF-8 format.

http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/fileformats.html

> **Chars**
>
> Lucene writes unicode character sequences as UTF-8 encoded bytes.
>
> **String**
>
> Lucene writes strings as UTF-8 encoded bytes. First the length, in bytes, is written as a VInt, followed by the bytes.
>
> String --> VInt, Chars

Comment: Is Lucene.Net supports both utf-8 and utf-16 encoding?

Answer (score 2):

Lucene does support unicode, but there are limitations.  For example some document readers don't support unicode.  Also, lucene does things like pluralize or un-pluralize words.  When you are using a foreign language some of that goes away.